# wxHtmlDCRenderer, how to correctly compute width

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I use `wxHtmlDCRenderer` to output rendered HTML text on a frame. The html text is simple:

```
<h4>Anderson-Darling Test</h4>
<p>p-value: 0.958<br>
A<sup>2</sup>: 0.13</p>
```

Since `wxHtmlDCRenderer` requires Width and Height to be set ahead of time, I use the following code to compute the size of the rendered-HTML text.

```
wxSize GetHTMLTextSize(wxWindow* window, const wxString& HTMLText, double PixelScaleFactor, double FontScaleFactor)
{
        wxClientDC dc(window);

        wxHtmlWinParser parser;
        parser.SetDC(&dc, PixelScaleFactor, FontScaleFactor);
        auto HTMLCell = (wxHtmlCell*)parser.Parse(HTMLText);

        int w = window->GetSize().GetWidth();
        HTMLCell->Layout(w);

        int MaxWidth = HTMLCell->GetMaxTotalWidth();
        int Width = HTMLCell->GetWidth();

        return wxSize(MaxWidth, HTMLCell->GetHeight());
}
```

The actual rendering of the HTML code on a device-context happens with the following piece of code:

```
void CHTMLTextBox::RenderHTML(wxDC* dc)
{
    double ScaleFactor = m_ParentWindow->GetDPIScaleFactor();

    if (m_Size == wxSize())
        m_Size =sys::util::GetHTMLTextSize(m_ParentWindow, m_HTMLText, ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor);


    //wxHtmlDCRenderer might change the user scale of DC
    double OldUsrScale_X, OldUsrScale_Y;
    dc->GetUserScale(&OldUsrScale_X, &OldUsrScale_Y);

    wxHtmlDCRenderer htmlDC;
    htmlDC.SetDC(dc, ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor);
    htmlDC.SetSize(m_Size.GetWidth(), m_Size.GetHeight());
    htmlDC.SetHtmlText(m_HTMLText);

    htmlDC.Render(m_StartPoint.x, m_StartPoint.y);

    int totalHeight = htmlDC.GetTotalHeight();
    int totalWidth = htmlDC.GetTotalWidth();

    //not sure if the following two lines needed at all??
    htmlDC.SetSize(totalWidth, totalHeight);
    htmlDC.Render(m_StartPoint.x, m_StartPoint.y);

    m_Size = wxSize(totalWidth, totalHeight);

    //restore user scale back
    dc->SetUserScale(OldUsrScale_X, OldUsrScale_Y);
}
```

As shown below, it renders the HTML text itself correctly. The computed Height is correct however, I am having problems with the width as shown in the below image:

[image]

The problem is that the width does not seem to be computed correctly as the first sentence (starting with h4 tag) does not fit as a single line but seems broken.

Btw, I am using wxWidgets 3.1.4 on Windows 10 (VS 2019).

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: can you try with the wxWebView?

Comment: I dont see a function to return the size of the rendered-html in wxWebView except the control's own size. For my application, the html text should be rendered (via wxDC) on a frame.

Comment: One quick and dirty fix that works is instead of `htmlDC.SetDC(dc, ScaleFactor, ScaleFactor);` to use `htmlDC.SetDC(dc, ScaleFactor, 1.0);`. However, this has its own problems when the Windows OS uses a scaling factors greater than 150%. At least that seems to be what `wxHtmlWindow` seems to be doing (...src/html/htmlwin.cpp, line# 499).

Comment: AFAICS doing what you do should work, but perhaps you're just passing a too small width to `Layout()`? If you want to avoid line wrapping, try using something huge, like 10000 instead -- and then size the window using the computed cell size (and use the scrollbars if necessary).

Comment: @VZ. It seems that `HTMLCell->GetWidth()` just returns the given width and `HTMLCell->GetMaxTotalWidth();` does the actual computation. I use `CHTMLTextBox` as an interactive object on a chart and it shows a tooltip as well. So setting it to a huge width wont work for my case. Seems like the `FontScaleFactor` does the trick but this itself causes when OS' scaling factor is changed to something like 175%.

Comment: For the second part of my comment, this might be the problem : `#define TYPICAL_SCREEN_DPI  96.0` at https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/af1069374eedc50e1d69ad46ba905bf3258a0c99/src/html/htmprint.cpp#L58

Comment: Also worth looking `void wxHtmlCell::Layout(int WXUNUSED(w))` at https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/af1069374eedc50e1d69ad46ba905bf3258a0c99/src/html/htmlcell.cpp#L187

Comment: FWIW I've looked at my (old) code and it does `html_window->GetInternalRepresentation()->Layout(65 * html_window->GetCharWidth());` and then uses `Get{Width,Height}()` for the window size. This seemed to work fine, but in more recent code I did use `GetMaxTotalWidth()`, which worked for me too...

Comment: Does it work in all OS scales? My current scaling is 125% with display resolution of 1920x1080 (15.6 "). It works well here. At my other laptop where screen size is smaller and scale is larger, it does not work. I think the trick is to find the right `FontScaleFactor` for different display conditions.